# Clean URL test failed in Drupal 7.19 in a fresh install

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I just installed Drupal 7.19 and checked the configuration and found that the clean url test had failed.

I have the `.htaccess` file in my site's folder in www folder of wamp.

It is showing as:

> The clean URL test failed.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: What did you try? Please add more information, since your question is currently not fit on stackoverflow.

Comment: may be http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ will be a better place for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable Apache's `mod_rewrite` module. It has to be enabled for clear URLs to work.